# Deleting rows from a table cause index fragmentation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I removed some rows from a very large table. Then I ran a query that usually runs within a few seconds and found it to be running very slowly after deleting the rows. I re-built my index and ran my query and found it to be fast again. Could deleting those rows caused the index to be fragmented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, deleting rows affects the index and maintenance should take place to keep the index relatively in sync with existing data.

Rebuilding an index was likely unnecessary - you only need to do this if the physical fragmentation is 30 percent or more according to MS documentation.  `REORGANIZE` is usually a better choice - think of it as defraging the index.

This is a [good article series on SQL Server Index Fragmentation](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/02/index-fragmentation-findings-part-1-the-basics/).

Comment: Thank you that page you linked me is very helpful.

Comment: @Brent Ozar: Great article :)